# Convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty \exp(-a x^2 + b x^{2-\varepsilon}) x^n dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need to determine the convergence of the following improper integral
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \exp(-ax^2 + b x^{2-\varepsilon}) x^n dx,
$$
where $a > 0$, $b>0$, $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$, $n \geq 1$.

We mainly use comparison test. But what is there to compare the function with?

If $\varepsilon = 0$, we easily obtain the divergent integral if $a \leq b$.

If $\varepsilon \in (0, 1]$, we can calculate

$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \exp(-ax^2 + b x^{2-\varepsilon}) x^n = 0.
$$
(the necessary convergence condition)

If $\varepsilon = 1$, we can calculate using Wolfram Mathematica
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \exp(-ax^2 + b x) x^n dx = \frac{1}{2} a^{-\frac{n}{2}-1} \left(b \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n}{2}+1;\frac{3}{2};\frac{b^2}{4
   a}\right)+\sqrt{a} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{b^2}{4
   a}\right)\right)
$$
and so, in this case this integral converges.

How can I establish the convergence of this integral in the general case? What function I should use to estimate this integral?

Comment: The idea is that of the three factors $e^{-ax^2}$, $e^{bx^{2-\varepsilon}}$, and $x^n$, the first factor's decay dominates the growth of the other two factors. So you could compare to $e^{-x^{2-\varepsilon/2}}$ or to $e^{-\frac a2 x^2}$. For that matter, you could even compare to $e^{-x}$ or to $x^{-2}$.

Comment: If $\epsilon = 0$, doesn't the convergence of the integral depend on the values of $a$ and $b$?  If $a > b$, shouldn't the integral still converge?

Comment: @user6247850, indeed, I was wrong.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks! Indeed, $\lim_{x\to \infty} \exp(-a x^2 + b x^{2-\varepsilon}) / \exp(-a x^2 / 2) = 0$, so my integral converges if the integral $\int_0^\infty \exp(-a x^2 / 2) x^n dx$ converges. The last integral converges, and we can evaluate it.

Comment: If $a>b$ and $\epsilon=0$, the simple  $\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)
   (a-b)^{-\frac{n+1}{2}}$